# How to get file name from downloaded file C# (Missing Content Disposition)

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to write a downloader using .Net Framework C#. Except I can't figure out how to get the file names of the downloaded files.

I've looked at people saying to use Content-Disposition, but I tried out a bunch of sites and none of them have it in the header. The following code returns null.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
     return response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
}
```

I've also tried parsing the file name from the URI, but this only works for sites that have the file name directly in it.

Is it simply me being unlucky that the page doesn't have the proper header? Tried sites include CNET, PortableApps, Google Drive, Facebook Messenger Attachments. The URL when pasted into a browser (Firefox, Chrome) will download the file immediately (or display in browser when it's a pdf)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be in the link or so you mean those sites where it says "your download will start shortly"?

Comment: Not always, for example, this download link from google drive has no anything related to the file name: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JnTi7N0NcaTgSFoprvSbXxSIVWO24DvymJOx1p7Iq3E/export?format=xlsx&id=1JnTi7N0NcaTgSFoprvSbXxSIVWO24DvymJOx1p7Iq3E

Well, that is a bad example, cause there is a Content-Disposition header in it.

For example, this one http://www.example.com/download.php?id=10 Where the link is php generated.

Comment: Ah...some indirect thing

Comment: An http resource is not required to have a human-readable name. You can read its format/media type from the `Content-Type` header. Which also needs a "translator" of sort. The Google file you linked has a Content-Type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". So it's a "Document" of the type you see. When a "Content-Disposition" is not provided (common), you should have a content mapper that can translate it to ".xlsx" (you can find those references on-line). The resource name could be the `httpResponse.ResponseUri.Segments.Last()` (to URLDecode as a precaution).

Comment: Take a look at this CodeProject demo [Multi-thread Segmented Download Manager](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21053/MyDownloader-A-Multi-thread-C-Segmented-Download-M)